# Get missing value errors while draw a bar-line mixed and dual y axis plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a data example as follows:

```
          date     a            b
0    2010/3/31  12.2   71,168.00 
1    2010/6/30  11.4  149,914.90 
2    2010/9/30  10.9  231,281.60 
3   2010/12/31  10.6  320,102.60 
4    2011/3/31  10.2   98,902.80 
5    2011/6/30  10.1  209,217.00 
6    2011/9/30   9.9  324,440.50 
7   2011/12/31   9.6  451,480.10 
8    2012/3/31   8.1  106,938.50 
9    2012/6/30   7.9  225,695.90 
10   2012/9/30   7.8  349,612.90 
11  2012/12/31   7.9  486,983.30
```

I have used the code below to draw a **bar-line mixed and dual y axis plot**:

```
df$date <- as.yearqtr(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

df_m <- melt(df, id.vars='date')

df_m_x <- df_m %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("b")) 

df_m_ratio_x <- df_m %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("a")) %>%
coeff = 1/10000

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df_m_x,  aes(x = date, y = value, fill = variable), alpha = 1.0, stat = 'identity') +
  geom_line(data = df_m_ratio_x,  aes(x = date, y = value, col = variable), size = 0.5) +
  geom_point(data = df_m_ratio_x,  aes(x = date, y = value, col = variable), size = 1) +
  xlab('') +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "dollar",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name = "%")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("a" = "#00AFBB")) +
  scale_x_yearqtr(limits = c(min(df$date), max(df$date)), format = "%YQ%q")
```

Out:

[image]

Howerver, I get an `Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_bar)` at same time, you may find that in the plot, the data points of `2010/3/31` and `2012/12/31` are missing.

Someone could help me to figure out where did I do wrong to raise this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's probably because of the limits you have set on your x axis don't contain the outer values of the rectangles drawn by the bars. With scales v1.1.1 try setting `scale_x_yearqtr(oob = scales::oob_keep, ...)`.

Comment: I’ll try with your solutions and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: It works, you may answer the question and i'll accept it if you like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works after adding `scale_x_yearqtr(oob = scales::oob_keep, ...)`, thanks to @teunbrand.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df_m_x,  aes(x = date, y = value, fill = variable), alpha = 1.0, stat = 'identity') +
  geom_line(data = df_m_ratio_x,  aes(x = date, y = value, col = variable), size = 0.5) +
  geom_point(data = df_m_ratio_x,  aes(x = date, y = value, col = variable), size = 1) +
  xlab('') +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "dollar",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name = "%")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("a" = "#00AFBB")) +
  scale_x_yearqtr(oob = scales::oob_keep, limits = c(min(df$date), max(df$date)), format = "%YQ%q")
```